# What is the meaning of a broken tenuto mark?

Tags: notation

A manuscript I have uses what seems to be a broken tenuto mark like this in a few places:

[image: Broken tenuto mark]

It's always on tremolo notes and always in a string part (violin & cello); the composer is 19th century American. What does the marking mean?